# How to sort RECORDS by field

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have a page, where I output teasers from certain records (not pages). I have realized this with a typoscript which you find below. This script get parameters via a fluid script:

```
<f:for each="{data.tx_mask_cnt_nwsdat_teaser_rec}" as="data_item">
 <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dateteaser-man-x" data="{uid: data_item.uid, recid: data_item.records}"/>
</f:for>
```

The variable "recid" contains the IDs from the records, from which the teasers should be generated. This works as expected - the records will be sorted in the order of the IDs in "recid",  But now I want to sort the records by the field "tx_mask_cnt_textpic_uni_date" - how can I achieve this?

```
lib.dateteaser-man-x {

    wrap = |

    10 = RECORDS
    10 {

        source.data = field:recid  // --> comma separated list of record-ids

        dontCheckPid = 1
        tables = tt_content

        conf.tt_content = COA
        conf.tt_content {

            wrap = <div class="teaserbox-item-wrapper">|</div>

            # Datum / Symbol
            10 = CASE
            10 {
                key.field = tx_mask_cnt_textpic_uni_teaserlabel

                1 = COA
                1 {

                    wrap = <div class="tb-labelfield">|</div>

                    10 = TEXT
                    10 {
                        wrap = <span class="tb-date day">|</span>
                        field = tx_mask_cnt_textpic_uni_date  // --> field to sort by (format YYY-MM-DD)
                        strtotime = 1
                        strftime = %e
                    }

                    20 = TEXT
                    20 {
                        wrap = <span class="tb-date monthyear">|</span>
                        field = tx_mask_cnt_textpic_uni_date
                        strtotime = 1
                        strftime = %b. %y
                    }

                }

                2 = TEXT
                2 {
                    wrap = <div class="tb-labelfield">|</div>
                    value = <span class="tb-info"><i data-feather="info"></i></span>
                }

                default = TEXT
                default {
                    wrap = <div class="tb-labelfield">|</div>
                    value = <span class="tb-info"><i data-feather="info"></i></span>
                }

            }

            # Text
            30 = TEXT
            30 {
                wrap = <div class="tb-content">|</div>
                field = tx_mask_cnt_textpic_uni_teasertxt
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Typo3 V.9.5.8

Comment: Just an idea: you could use the viewhelper 'v:iterator.sort'

Answer (score 0):

You should go for `CONTENT` instead of `RECORDS` in this case

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html

`CONTENT` makes use of `select` and that again will give you `uidInList` and `orderBy`

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Select.html#select